# Why doesn't my Fragment's layout change dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am making a `Fragment` whose layout is supposed to change dynamically. Here is it's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/root">

</LinearLayout>
```

In the `onCreateView()`, a `ListView` or `GridView` is added programatically based on the orientation. However, on configuration change, nothing happens. Here is how I handle configuration change:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            root = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.root);
            root.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            listView = new ListView(getActivity());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            root.addView(listView,params);
        }else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            root = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.root);
            root.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            gridView = new GridView(getActivity());
            gridView.setNumColumns(2);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(150);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            root.addView(gridView,params);
        }
    }
```

I tried removing all the views on configuration change but nothing happens. **What needs to be changed here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you "registered" your Activity to configChanges?

You need to add:

```
 <activity android:name="com.bla.bla.YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```

in your Manifest in order to get calls to onConfigurationChanged...

EDIT:

However, the better way would be to use two different layouts in the different layout folders (layout-land or layout-port). One with a gridview and the other one with a listview. That way you don't need to handle the config change "manually". Just handle the differences in onCreate...
(Your Activity will be destroyed and created again on config change...)

Comment: The requirement is to have a single `Activity` and let it host various fragments :)

Comment: Yes, I would also do it that way (the one described in the edit...)

Comment: @jpm What if I need to have a `Navigation Drawer`. In that case, isn't  letting one Activity host various fragments a better option ? :) Sorry, I am new to this

Comment: No problem. I'm not really sure what you mean. If the layout that you posted is everything in this activity, I don't see a reason to use various fragments. One Activity, two layout files (with the same name in two different folders ( see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ) ) should do the trick...

Comment: @jpm here, I was just testing if `Fragments` can indeed change layout based on orientation. In the final app, there will a nav drawer. With multiple activities, wont there be a lot of XML repetition ? :)

Comment: Ah ok I see...Well I'm not sure how a NavigationDrawer is implemented best. But you might be right that fragments would make sense in that case. But that doesn't change the behavior on orientation change. Fragments will also be destroyed and recreated, and you can also use different layouts for the different orientations